# How do I get the scanner media stream on an android MC40 using C# and xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

[image]

How do I access the scanner stream on a Motorola MC40N0, using code in C# and Xamarin Android? How do I get the identifier that corresponds to it?

I know that I can get notifications by using `Stream.Notification`. I can also access alarms by using `Stream.Alarms`. I want to know how to get the scanner media stream. I am trying to change the volume of the scanner stream, so I need the `Stream` value to pass to `SetStreamVolume()`:

```
audioManger.SetStreamVolume(
    /* what stream goes here? */,
    volume,
    VolumeNotificationFlags.AllowRingerModes
);
```

Comment: did you find this one: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Media.MediaPlayer.SetVolume/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

motorola/zebra said this stream should not exist. Therefore (in my own opinion), there is probably not a way to interact with this stream using programming.